# How do I specify a boxed field can be nullable in my Realm migration code?

Tags: android, realm, kotlin

I'm using **Kotlin** and I want to add a new field to a `RealmObject` and that field can be nullable. Here's what I have in my migration:

```
val schema = realm.schema.get(ZOLA_NOTIFICATION)
if (!(schema?.hasField("agentId") ?: false)) {
    schema.addField("agentId", Long::class.java)
}
```

However, I receive an error message when this migration is run:

```
Non-fatal Exception: io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException
Field 'agentId' does not support null values in the existing Realm file. Either set @Required, use the primitive type for field 'agentId' or migrate using RealmObjectSchema.setNullable().
```

How do I specify that the `Long::class.java` should be the nullable type in the migration code?

Comment: use RealmObjectSchema.setNullable()

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Unfortunately,

```
Long::class.java // kotlin
```

is equivalent to

```
long.class // java
Long::class.javaPrimitiveType // kotlin
```

---

But what you need to add for nullable Long in Realm is

```
Long.class // java
```

So you need to use

```
Long::class.javaObjectType // Long.class
```

---

In migration, you can turn a required field to nullable field using [`RealmObjectSchema.setNullable(String field, boolean nullable)`](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmObjectSchema.html#setNullable-java.lang.String-boolean-) method.